# Can't use facebook to login because user model setting in local passport

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to build a login system with Facebook, Google and local passport, I am using Node.js, passport.js, and ORM to finish it, but I faced one problem now, my user model is like below

```
const User = connection.define('user', {   googleID: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,   },   facebookID: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,   },   firstname: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          notEmpty: true,
        },

  lastname: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          notEmpty: true,
        },

  username: {
          type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        },

  email: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          validate: {
              isEmail: true,
            },
        },

  password: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
        },

  last_login: {
          type: Sequelize.DATE,
         }, });
```

After this setting, whenever I want to log on my website through Facebook, it kept showing SEQUELIZE ERROR, password required! I know it the reason is I don't have password while signing in with Facebook, but what can I do with this issue? I saw this page on GitHub https://github.com/feathersjs/authentication/issues/168
but I still have no clue in using this feathers-joi tool, can anyone give me some advice? Thank you

Here is my Facebook.js code

```
const passport = require('passport');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/User');
const keys = require('../secret/keys.js');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then(user => {
    done(null, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: keys.facebookClientID,
  clientSecret: keys.facebookClientSecret,
  callbackURL: '/auth/facebook/callback',
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  User.findOne({ where: { facebookID: profile.id } }).then(existinguser => {
    if (existinguser) {
      //Nothing will happen, the ID already exists
      done(null, existinguser);
    }else {
      User.create({ facebookID: profile.id }).then(user => done(null, user));
    }
  });
}));
```

My passport.js would be like below(Still need some fix)

```
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');


module.exports = function(passport, user) {


    var User = user;

    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;


    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy(

        {

            usernameField: 'email',

            passwordField: 'password',

            passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback

        },



        function(req, email, password, done) {

            var generateHash = function(password) {

                return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);

            };



            User.findOne({
                where: {
                    email: email
                }
            }).then(function(user) {

                if (user)

                {

                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'That email is already taken'
                    });

                } else

                {

                    var userPassword = generateHash(password);

                    var data =

                        {
                            email: email,

                            password: userPassword,

                            firstname: req.body.firstname,

                            lastname: req.body.lastname

                        };

                    User.create(data).then(function(newUser, created) {

                        if (!newUser) {

                            return done(null, false);

                        }

                        if (newUser) {

                            return done(null, newUser);

                        }

                    });

                }

            });

        }

    ));

}
```

Comment: Either you can set `password` field as blank string while login with facebook or you can set `allowNull` to `true`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice, currently I don't want to set my password to allow Null, can you tell me how to set password field as blank while I am login with fb? thanks

Comment: Show me your passport code pls

Comment: Hi, I showed it in the page, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: keys.facebookClientID,
  clientSecret: keys.facebookClientSecret,
  callbackURL: '/auth/facebook/callback',
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  User.findOne({ where: { facebookID: profile.id } }).then(existinguser => {
    if (existinguser) {
      //Nothing will happen, the ID already exists
      done(null, existinguser);
    }else {
        var object = {
            facebookID: profile.id,
            password: ""
        }
      User.create(object).then(user => done(null, user));
    }
  });
}));
```

Comment: Thank you, would the condition be something like if(facebook.id!=NULL){data.password = " "} right ?

Comment: Thank you so much!!